# variable is in main function then why is it out of scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have created variable upperCaseAfter in the main function than why I get the warning out of scope when I used it later by assigning to arr[i]?

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  arr =str.split(" ");
  //to adjust upper or lower cases before we even replace the words and store it in new variable if after value has to be changed 

  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {   
    if(before[0]===before[0].toUpperCase()){
     var upperCaseAfter=after[0].toUpperCase() + after.substring(1);   
    }
    if (arr[i]===before &&  before[0]===before[0].toUpperCase()){          
      arr[i]=upperCaseAfter;      
     } else 
     if(arr[i]==before && before[0]===before[0].toLowerCase()) {
          arr[i]=after;
     }      

   }
   str=arr.join(" ");       
 return str;
}
myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");
```

Answer (score 0):

You redeclared it inside `myReplace` function:

```
if(before[0]===before[0].toUpperCase()){
 var upperCaseAfter=after[0].toUpperCase() + after.substring(1);   
}
```

The JS compiler thinks you want to refer to this variable inside `myReplace` when you do:

```
arr[i]=upperCaseAfter;
```

and then it's out of scope because you declared it inside the `if` statement.

Solution: rename `upperCaseAfter` to something else when inside `myReplace` function or remove the keyword `var` to use the `upperCaseAfter` you declared in `main` (the outer scope).

Comment: I did the following changes:-

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution that I just have to declare variable upperCaseAfter before the for loop then i do not get any warning.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following change it took the error away !

```
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
      arr =str.split(" ");
      var upperCaseAfter;
  //to adjust upper or lower cases before we even replace the words and store it 
    in new variable if after value has to be changed 

  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {   
    if(before[0]===before[0].toUpperCase()){
     upperCaseAfter=after[0].toUpperCase() + after.substring(1);   
    }
    if (arr[i]===before &&  before[0]===before[0].toUpperCase()){          
      arr[i]=upperCaseAfter;      
     } else 
     if(arr[i]==before && before[0]===before[0].toLowerCase()) {
          arr[i]=after;
     }      

   }
   str=arr.join(" ");       
 return str;
}
myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped");
```